# why is this cypher query so slow with only ~30 nodes and say 50 relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
MATCH
  (t:T)-[:Rel]-(o:Espresso)-[:Rel]->(l:Location)<-[:Rel]-(p:Espresso {id:"ttt"})-[:Rel]->t,
  o--(:Rating)--p
RETURN
  distinct o.id AS otherId,
  l.location AS location,
  t.hour AS hour,
  t.day as day
```

It times out. I tried it as a `where` clause and using `with` but no difference. The first part before the `,` executes quickly...

Comment: Welcom to stack overflow @vivace, please format and indent you question to get better answer. You'll find help there: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Your query is almost incomprehensible. Try breaking it down step by step using `with` and you will certainly see better results. You should certainly also be using better relationship names rather than recycling the same one for all relationships.

Comment: Welcome!  As a modeling point, I'd suggest having the field on `Location` nodes be `name`, not `location`.  It's odd getting something like location.location

Comment: side note: Time doesn't sound like something that should need a node of its own....

Comment: sorry about the formatting. Thanks for the comments bt the modeling is quite sound. I am not recycling anything, i am searching for a subgraph comprised of only that relationship type. (there are other relationship tyes as well but not in this query)

Comment: try to use **PROFILE** in front of your query, also your second path causes a potential explosion, perhaps check better if you have a connection there with `shortestPath(o-[:REL*2..2]-p)` and optionally a `WHERE clause`

Comment: If your database is so small it makes sense to share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to have fixed it.
MATCH (t:Time)-[:Rel]-(o:Espresso)-[:Rel]->(l:Location)<-[:Rel]-(p:Espresso {id:"ttt"})-[:Rel]->t with DISTINCT o,p,t,l MATCH (o)--(rat:Rating)--(p) RETURN DISTINCT o.id as otherId, l.location as location, t.start as start, t.day as day

thanks

Comment: Do you have an index on :Espresso(id) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are only 30 nodes/50 relationships in the whole database?  That seems really odd...  Have you previously created/deleted a lot of nodes, maybe as part of experimentation?  If so, you may want to try restarting the server.

Answer (score 1):

Improvements In your query/structure

1. Don't use "," in match it will work as a Cartesian Product.
2. You are using same relationship between all nodes that is :Rel
   note - Always try to use unique relationship names in different types of nodes.
3. first go through this doc
   http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-query-lang.html
4. also check this how to write a optimized queries
   http://www.slideshare.net/neo4j/optimizing-cypher-32550605

Comment: i am not using the same relationship between all nodes. I have many different types of relationships. Its just that in this query i am searching for a pattern in the :Rel relationship subgraph.